# What I Am? - Essence of every living

Tags: riddle, word

> *In the essence of every living.*
>   *And even in those who borders the live.*
>   *There, I am.*
>
> *From the letters, I am the first.*
>   *Five times the seven, five times the six and five times the one.*
>   *But then, we have two circles.*

What I am?

Notes:

- This have a unique answer and it is a single word.
- Hopefully it won't make sense to anything else, ensuring the uniqueness.
- The challenge contains enough information for people find out what is this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Adenine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenine

In the essence of every living.
And even in those who borders the live.
There, I am.

> Has to do with cellular respiration, and is a component of DNA/RNA.

From the letters, I am the first

> Starts with A

Five times the seven, five times the six and five times the one.

> The chemical composition is $C5N5H5$ (5 carbon, 5 nitrogen, 5 hydrogen)

But then, we have two circles.

> The molecule is 2 circles in shape

Comment: Ah, I read the rest of the page, I think I know which part you were hinting at now, and I learned something new!